# Simulink version of AnyLogic component

Tags: matlab, simulink, anylogic

Does anybody know what components in Simulink (MATLAB package) are analogs for AnyLogic components? (e.g: source, buffer, delay, sink).
Or how can I easily simulate behavior of AnyLogic model in MATLAB?
Maybe there are some cool magic tools?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether or not there is an easy way to convert from an AnyLogic model to a Simulink model, I doubt it. I haven't seen any conversion tools like that.

I have a feeling you're just going to have to rebuild your AnyLogic model in Simulink if you want to simulate your models in MATLAB. I would start by looking through the [**Block List**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f4-4889.html) and [**Function List**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/bq3cxmi.html) links on this [Simulink documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/). You should be able to find analogous components to those in your AnyLogic model.

Answer (score 1):

AnyLogic is one of the best tools for business simulation and Matlab is the best engineering tool. But they have different notations.So in the most cases conversion is just impossible! E.g. to convert DE model of airport into Matlab.

My suggestion: use Matlab for engineering tasks and AnyLogic for business simulation.